# Count data if row is true excel

Tags: excel

I have this Data:

```
var number
a   1
a   4
a   30
b   4
b   50
b   6
b   4
ab  1
```

I need to find the sum of each time a (var occurs X the number next column right) in excel.

In the case above the answer would be:

```
a = 36
b = 65
```

How can I write a formula for this in excel?  Can I do this in excel?

Comment: Is `ab` the only other combination? Or is there an `ab`, `abc`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are counting the last one as well, I would use this formula:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"*"&D2&"*",B:B)
```

Here, there is the value `a` in cell B2 and I can drag the formula down for B instead of typing a whole new formula. Handy if you have many like those to look for.

[image]

Comment: @Jerry Nicer solution than the answer I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have the table you published above in cells A1:B8. In order to do the calculating you would like to do you need to use the array-functionality in Excel. The following syntax in a cell will do:

```
=SUM(IF("a"=A1:A8,B1:B8))
```

However, instead of ENTER you need to press COMMAND+SHIFT+ENTER (I am on a Mac so it might be that Windows has a slightly different key combo. The result is that the formula now reads like:

```
{=SUM(IF("a"=A1:A8,B1:B8))}
```

This will give you 35 and not 36, but in a similar manner you could sum all the columns with 'ab' and then add that up to the sum of the 'a' columns.

Good luck!